# Tkinter python Button not following cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry('450x500')
root.config(bg='#deeffa')

def follow(parent):
    root.bind('\<Motion\>',lambda event,parent=parent:center_mouser(event,parent))
    parent.but.config(command=stop)
def stop():
    root.unbind('\<Motion\>')
def center_mouser(event,parent):
    root.config(cursor="none")
    parent.but.place(x=event.x,y=event.y, anchor='center')
class moving_but():
    def __init__(self,but=None,val=0):
        self.val=val
        self.but=Button(borderwidth=1,text=str(self.val),command=lambda parent=self:follow(parent))
        self.but.pack()

i=moving_but(val=10)

root.mainloop()
```

So I am trying to make a Button that follows the center of the cursor but I have found that tkinte does not allows this and will make the button flicker between the cursor and top left corner. If you do event.x-50 for example the programme works perfectly but obviously removing the purpose of the button. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I've slightly changed the callbacks, and used `.winfo_pointerx()/.winfo_pointery()` functions to compute the position:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("450x500")
root.config(bg="#deeffa")


def follow():
    root.config(cursor="none")
    root.bind("<Motion>", center_mouser)
    i.but.config(command=stop)


def stop():
    root.config(cursor="")
    root.unbind("<Motion>")
    i.but.config(command=follow)


def center_mouser(event):
    x = root.winfo_pointerx() - root.winfo_rootx() - i.but.winfo_width() // 2
    y = root.winfo_pointery() - root.winfo_rooty() - i.but.winfo_height() // 2

    i.but.place(x=x, y=y, anchor="nw")


class moving_but:
    def __init__(self, but=None, val=0):
        self.val = val
        self.but = Button(
            borderwidth=1,
            text=str(self.val),
            command=follow,
        )
        self.but.pack()


i = moving_but(val=10)
root.config(cursor="")
root.mainloop()
```

Creates this application:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since the binding is on `root`, it will be inherited by its child widgets.  That is the binding callback will be triggered when the mouse is moving within the button as well and the event (x, y) will be relative to the button, not root window.

You should move the button only when the event is triggered by root window:

```py
def center_mouser(event, parent):
    if event.widget is root:
        parent.but.place(x=event.x, y=event.y, anchor='center')
```